# Strange difference in JNI and C between a function return and direct assignment in a value

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I know there are similar questions about simple variables in C, but I guess this one is a bit different...

I have an int value named occurrences where I want to assign to it a value from a function like that:

```
occurrences = GPOINTER_TO_INT(g_hash_table_lookup(Sip_income2, headersDigest[i]));
```

My problem is that when i try to assign to this variable a value by using the hashtable_lookup function ,as I already showed above, then this value in java is equal to 0.

However, if I assign a value in a variable occurrence e.g

```
occurrences = 5;
```

and then i pass this variable as a parameter to a java function with JNI this value is indeed equal to 5 in java, so there is no problem with that.

What should the problem that causes all that and is there any possible solution?

Comment: Most likely the function returns NULL which is then cast to int 0. Did  you test the return value from g_hash_table_lookup not being NULL?

Comment: `GPOINTER_TO_INT()`?  How do you know a pointer fits into an `int`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't...but what's the alternative way to do that???